# How to run nginx using the nginx user

Tags: linux, nginx

I have installed nginx on ec2, and when I star it, I see it runs using the `ec2-user`.

My impression is that it is not advisable to run the webserver with `ec2-user` but another user.

When I look at the default configuation at  `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` i see `user nginx;` showing that a user nginx could be used.

Question now is, how do I use the `nginx` user to run `nginx`. I currently can control nginx by using sudo. If I do not, I get the following error:

```
systemctl stop nginx
Failed to stop nginx.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status nginx.service' for details.
```

How do I get to be able to control nginx like this, but with the `ngin` user?

when I try to switch to the user, I get the following message:

```
sudo -iu nginx
This account is currently not available.
```

But when I try to add the `nginx` user, I get the following message:

```
sudo useradd nginx
useradd: user 'nginx' already exists
```

SO I am not sure the correct way of dealing with this.

Comment: This is the user NGINX workers will use, not master process that you start as root (with `sudo`). Run `ps aux | grep nginx` and you'll see them running as `nginx` user.

Comment: so you suggesting everything is fine, and I should just go ahead and use things like systemctl stop|start nginx etc in my scripts?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It is NGINX workers that accept requests and it essential that they run by an unprivileged user so that they cannot access anything dangerous.

Comment: Thanks. If you feel like it, you can submit this as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: The question is likely to be deleted because it belong to another site (serverfault). Don't bother :)

Comment: if there is a way for me to migrate it to serverfault I will...but not sure there is :/